# Is it possible to say "So was I" in English language?

Tags: grammaticality

Does the following sentence sound natural? "She was terribly upset and so was I". I can't find any examples of using this construction on the Internet.

Comment: What about this: https://quizlet.com/41713880/so-do-i-so-does-he-sentences-to-practise-flash-cards/

Comment: "I can't find any examples of using this construction on the Internet."  Really? a simple search for the phrase "so was I" yields thousands of examples.

Comment: see https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51832/subject-auxiliary-inversion-in-elliptical-sentences-eg-so-am-i

Comment: I get 3 examples of "she was *very* upset, and so was I." Surely they are equally good sentences. & both sound fine to me.

Answer (score 3):

Your phrase

> **so was I**

is the past tense of

> **I am also**
>   **me too**

and has the same meaning as

> **I was also**

so, in a conversation

> P1: I was really scared during the storm last night.
>   P2: **So was I**!